# how to add a dockerfile to jekyll deployed to gitlab

Tags: docker, gitlab, jekyll, gitlab-ci

I host my jekyll website on gitlab with shared runner. I would like to add dockerfile to it and cache the build process. I found a docker image [here](https://github.com/envygeeks/jekyll-docker). It says usage is,

```
export JEKYLL_VERSION=3.8
docker run --rm \
  --volume="$PWD:/srv/jekyll" \
  --volume="$PWD/vendor/bundle:/usr/local/bundle" \
  -it jekyll/jekyll:$JEKYLL_VERSION \
  jekyll build
```

Where to add this code. Can I add somewhere in `gitlab-ci.yml` file?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow "[Building a blog with Jekyll, Docker and GitLab](https://voutzinos.com/blog/jekyll-docker-gitlab-blog/)" from [**Florian Voutzinos**](https://github.com/florianv)

It will run Jekyll inside a Docker container to compile and preview the static site mounted locally to the `dist` folder.

It uses a `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'

services:
  jekyll:
    image: jekyll/jekyll
    volumes:
      - ./src:/srv/jekyll/site
      - ./dist:/srv/jekyll/_site
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
```

And a gitlab-ci.yml:

```
pages:
  image: alpine:latest
  script:
  - cp -R ./dist ./public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

Comment: I get `Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /srv/jekyll/site/./.gitignore` while running `docker-compose run jekyll jekyll new site`. I didn't install virtualBox